# How to measure PWM output with simulavr?

Tags: simulation, pwm

I have successfully setup **simulavr** for an embedded application testing environment (Atmel-644PA µC).

The good: I have compiled on both Debian and Windows/MinGW environments, and created several Python UI's with PyQt4. I have been successful so far with serial, digital, and analog input and output.

The latest challenge: I am currently grappling with measuring **PWM** output. I have created the usual Net with two Pins, I can see the changing state with the 'Pin.SetInState()' method, and have tried to make calculation with the SystemClock, to no avail.

Net setup:

```
# MCU Pin PD4
elf.pinD4 = self.dev.GetPin("D4")
# Pin to receive PWM data from pin PD4
self.pinControl= OutputPinPWM("pinControl", 5.0)
## Net for MCU Pin PD4
self.netPD4 = pysimulavr.Net()
self.netPD4.Add(self.pinD4)
self.netPD4.Add(self.pinControl)
```

Thanks in advance...